# Windows 8.1 Shell Launcher (Embedded Lockdown Manager) Not Launching Shell

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-embedded-8

I'm trying to set up the Windows 8.1 Shell Launcher within Embedded Lockdown Manager (ELM) to use my custom app as the windows shell.

Currently, I have it set up like this:

[image: Shell Launcher Setup]

When logged on as 'DefaultUser' the default shell gets started and not 'myapp'.

Here is the PowerShell script that ELM created for me:

```
Clear-Shells
Set-DefaultShell "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" 0
Add-Shell "DefaultUser" "c:\myapp.exe"
Set-CustomActions "DefaultUser" @(0,1,2,3) @(0,1,2,3)
```

Any ideas on how to get Shell Launcher to start up my shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ELM (and PowerShell scripts generated by ELM) leave out one important step, which is to change the shell from Explorer.exe to eShell.exe.  If you add the following to your script, it will work correctly:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name Shell -Value "eShell.exe"
```

eShell.exe is what does the work of launching the appropriate shell for a particular user, including Explorer if that is what is configured.